# is there a proper way to change a single pixel color in kivy canvas?

Tags: python, kivy

I have tried to make 2d array that store rectangle(with size=(1,1)) and color object, so it work like a new canvas on a kivy canvas, but it's laggy when the first time it create array of rectangle even when i just put 100x100 pixel, here's the code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Point, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Touch(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.new_window_size= None
        self.timer= 0
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_screen, 1/30)


    def update_screen(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            self.old_window_size= self.new_window_size
            self.new_window_size= Window.size
            if(self.old_window_size!= self.new_window_size):
                #i set 100x100 just to test
                self.w= 100 #self.new_window_size[0]
                self.h= 100 #self.new_window_size[1]
                self.color= []
                self.pixel= []
                for x in range(self.w):
                    temp_1= []
                    temp_2= []
                    for y in range(self.h):
                        print(x, y)
                        temp_1.append(Color(1, 1, 1, 1))
                        temp_2.append(Rectangle(pos= (x, y), size= (1, 1)))
                    self.color.append(temp_1)
                    self.pixel.append(temp_2)
            else:
                #update color
                self.color[self.timer][24].rgba= (0, 0, 0, 1)
                print(self.timer)
                self.timer+= 1

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Touch()

MyApp().run()
```

is there a proper way to change single pixel in kivy canvas class?

Answer (score 1):

To change just one pixel, you can use a `Rectangle` with size `(1,1)`. Most easily done using `kv`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Touch(Widget):
    pass

kv = '''
<Touch>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1   # the new pixel color
        Rectangle:
            pos: 200, 200   # The pixel that you want to set
            size: 1,1   # indicate that just one pixel is changed
'''

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Touch()

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: but, the problem with this is when you want to manipulate huge amount of pixel, you will have to create many rectangle object that make kivy lagging, is there a direct way to change only 1 pixel(?), even if there are, is it okay to use it?

Comment: So, you are not actually trying to change a single pixel. Please tell us what you are trying to accomplish by changing a huge amount of pixels? Perhaps changing a huge amount of individual pixels is not the best approach.

Comment: my final goal is to control all pixel color manually. for example i have 3 screen layer, where the first layer is the main layer, second layer show an image, and the third layer control the light. I can then put light from second layer to third layer and calculate pixel brightness like add second layer rgb into third layer rgb for each pixels. Last is main layer that show what part of image you want to see in a screen

Comment: I suggest doing all those calculations using something like [numpy](https://numpy.org/) or [Python Imaging Library](https://python-pillow.org/) and just use kivy to display the reults.

Comment: i assume you mean calculating each single pixel with it, if so, we still have to pass each pixel value to kivy isn't?

Comment: No, calculate the pixels to create an `Image` or a `Texture` that you display using kivy.